# yum repository install issue with cent os 7

Tags: centos

I have repository repo-server - where all build rpm resides [cent os 5]. Continuum-SCM-build dumps all rpms here.

server 1 client server [cent os 5] -- get the required rpms from repo-server

server 2 delivery server [cent os 5]-- get the required rpms from repo-server

server 3 log server [cent os 5]-- get the required rpms from repo-server

server 4 brain server [cent os 5 and cent os 7]-- get the required rpms from repo-server

Here there are multiple servers with brains installed for different clients.

Till now all brains servers on cent os 5. 
Now I have new machine with cent os 7 on it and that is causing the issue.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Error message

./install.sh sh-j**n-server-2.1.3.1-8  <-- install script is using yum command to install
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base extras j***n updates
Cleaning up everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
j***n                                                                                                                                                       |  951 B  00:00:00
j***n/primary
| 373 kB  00:00:00
Determining fastest mirrors
j***n
2199/2199

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sh-j***n-server.noarch 0:2.1.3.1-5 will be updated
---> Package sh-j***n-server.noarch 0:2.1.3.1-8 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: j***n = 2.1.3-6 for package: sh-j***n-server-2.1.3.1-8.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package j***n.noarch 0:2.1.3-3 will be updated
---> Package j***n.noarch 0:2.1.3-6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================

## Package                                             Arch                                      Version                                       Repository                                 Size

Updating:
 sh-j***n-server                                    noarch                                    2.1.3.1-8                                     j***n                                    8.2 k
Updating for dependencies:
 j***n                                              noarch                                    2.1.3-6                                       j***n                                    3.2 M

## Transaction Summary

Upgrade  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 3.2 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for j***n
(1/2): sh-j***n-server-2.1.3.1-8.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                          | 8.2 kB  00:00:00

### (2/2): j***n-2.1.3-6.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                      | 3.2 MB  00:00:00

Total                                                                                                                                                        4.0 MB/s | 3.2 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test

Transaction check error:
  file /opt/shsolutions/scripts from install of j***n-2.1.3-6.noarch conflicts with file from package t***g-client-2.1.3-1.noarch
  file /opt/shsolutions/scripts from install of j***n-2.1.3-6.noarch conflicts with file from package c**s-jb***t-listener-2.1.3-1.noarch
  file /opt/shsolutions/scripts from install of j***n-2.1.3-6.noarch conflicts with file from package p**s-r***l-ws-2.1.3-1.noarch
  file /opt/shsolutions/webapps from install of j***n-2.1.3-6.noarch conflicts with file from package p**s-r***l-ws-2.1.3-1.noarch

Comment: Not clear to me but did you rebuild your RPM packages on CentOS 7?

Comment: What commands did you run? What was the output of those commands? Sorry but it is really hard to help you given the information you have provided. Are you using "yum" or "rpm" command? Also your post title says CentOS 7, but your later say CentOS 5. Which is it?

Comment: No I haven't rebuild the RPM packages on Cent OS 7.

Comment: I am using Yum Install [package name] command..!

Comment: I have added extra notes to the question. Hope It helps see through clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS (and other Linux distributions) generally require you to rebuild your packages for each release.  There is no guarantee that an RPM or set of RPMs that install correctly on CentOS 5 will install correctly on CentOS 7.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to rebuild in cent os 7 and see the outcome.